# Tapping on google slides on android no longer works

Tags: google-slides

I use embedded google slides for my website. Earlier, on android, tapping on the slides used to progress the slides. However, I'm noticing that in version 92.xxxxx, it is no longer happening. The user needs to click on the > button on the bottom navigation bar to progress the slides. However, the problem with that is the > button is too small and the user needs to be very careful while clicking it. For our use case, tapping on the slides was the best way to progress with the slides.

The only solution I can think of is to progress the slides at a specific interval. However, it is hard to figure out an interval that suits all the users. Is there any other possible solution? Like can we create two external navigation buttons and send the signal to the embedded slide?